# Propriedade em objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Como posso fazer uma verificação em um *array* de objetos onde a intenção seria eliminar as duplicatas porém, preciso somar os valores de uma propriedade?

Exemplo: 
Tenho um *array* de objetos:

```
musicas = [{nome: 'Música 1', clicks: 1}, {nome: 'Música 1', clicks: 1}]
```

Preciso retornar um novo array a partir deste sem repetir as músicas porém somando o total de clicks.

Algo que ficasse assim:

```
musicas = [{nome: 'Música 1', clicks: 2}]
```

Comment: No teu exemplo tens `Musica` sem acento no `u` e com acento... são nomes diferentes?

Comment: São a mesma coisa. Esqueci o acento. Desculpe.

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro iterares esse array e criar um objeto ao mesmo tempo. Assim tens em comum o nome da musica e vais somando os cliques.

Algo assim:

```
var musicas = [{nome: 'Musica 1', clicks: 1}, {nome: 'Musica 1', clicks: 1}];

var res = {};
musicas.forEach(function(musica){
    if (!res[musica.nome]) res[musica.nome] = musica; // se ainda não estiver registada
    else res[musica.nome].clicks++; // já existe, somar o click
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); // {"Musica 1":{"nome":"Musica 1","clicks":2}}

// e se quiseres isso de volta numa array
var array = Object.keys(res).map(function(mus){
    return res[mus];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); // [{"nome":"Musica 1","clicks":2}]
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/gbw7hr1g/